# Intended travel date in UK visa

Tags: visas, uk

I live in India. While filling the application form for tourist visa to UK, I found a field called "Intended travel date". Should the travel date mentioned in this field be the same as my actual travel date or is a difference of 4-5 days ok?

Comment: If you know what your travel date will be, why put in something different? If you don't yet know what it will be, enter the date you intend to travel.

Answer (score 2):

A UK Standard visit visa will usually start from the date indicated in this field, therefore enter the actual or intended date. UKVI does not require you to pre-book travel reservations, so once you receive your visa you can travel whenever you like after the visa start date.